# Mockito - verify method is called with a specific parameter ( condition )

Tags: java, mockito

I have in my unit test the following line

```
verify(MyMock).handleError(any(ICallBack.class),any(BaseError.class) );
```

But what I want to write is a verify that tests if the base error class (2nd parameter) has

```
BaseError::errorCode = 3
```

How do I do it?
Is it only with argument capture?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use an appropriate matcher for the second argument. For example:

```
verify(MyMock).handleError(any(ICallBack.class), eq(new BaseError(3)));
```

assuming that this instance would be equal to any `BaseError` instance with this error code. You can also implement a custom `ArgumentMatcher<BaseError>` and implement the logic where you return `true` if the given instances `errorCode` is `3` e.g. by:

```
verify(MyMock).handleError(any(ICallBack.class), 
                           argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<BaseError> {
   @Override
   public boolean matches(Object baseError) {
     return ((BaseError) baseError).errorCode == 3;
   }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. equals is not implemented . How can I implement matcher?

Comment: This is a great answer. Just fixed two parts in your answer :  A. surrounded "new ArgumentMatcher<BaseError>" with "argThat()" so it will compile.  (HandleError receives BaseError and not ArgumentMatcher<BaseError>).B. Added Assert (as it is a considered a hack)
Other than that - it works. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the assertion. Mockito will provide you with proper feedback on a non-matching invocation. The `AssertionError` on the other hand does not provide you with this information.

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

```
     doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments()
                assertTrue((long)args[1], 3);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(MyMock).handleError(any(ICallBack.class),any(BaseError.class) );
```

Comment: I would not recommend this, this will give you a less detailed feedback from the error. Rather use the Mockito verification.